# How can I solve an encoding error while reading in a modified .csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to load up a CSV in a form on my site, and I keep hitting an error which confuses me. I have form that allows me to upload a .csv file (written only utf-8, standard English characters), and all I want to do is make assure that it will only be uploaded if it has a certain set of column names (note: order of column names is not important in this case).

My code is so far written as below (along with the desired column names):

```
data_dictionary_csv = cleaned_data['document_file'].read().decode("utf-8-sig").splitlines()[0]
header = data_dictionary_csv.split(',')
column_names= ["Table Name","Column Name", "Column Description", "ValueCode","ValueDescription"]
```

When I have my standard .csv file, it uploads with no problems. But I decided to run a test to make sure that there weren't any problems, and so I made blank workbook in Excel, copied and pasted the content from .csv file from before, BUT I added in a word into one of the column names. What should have happened was an error would get raised that would alert the user that the .csv's column names would need to changed. Instead, I end up getting this error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 1223: invalid continuation byte csv file
```

I have tried altering the `.decode()` argument to different codecs, but I'm not sure why me adding one word would cause this problem. Can someone give me some tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, when you are creating a new Excel file that you want to use a .csv, you need to explicitly save it as a .csv with UTF-8 encoding. In my previous approach, I think I saved it somewhat differently, which lead to the file being configured slightly differently. The incorrectly formatted .csv file can now be uploaded and raises the proper errors.